Convergence speed of decreasing sequence of points in a Poisson Random Field
I am stuck at one exercise about the Poisson Random Field I have trying to solve for the last days.
We are in the standard probability setting, given is $\beta \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ and a Poisson Random Field $\Pi$ with density
$$
\mu_{\beta}(dt) = \mathbb{1}_{t > 0}t^{-\beta}dt
$$
We have to show that there exist random variables such that almost surely
$$
X_n > X_{n+1}\text{, } \lim_{n \to \infty}X_n = 0 \text{ and } \Pi = \{X_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
and then the part where I am lost. We also have to show that there exist $C,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n^cX_n = C
$$
I know how to solve the first part and I also have the density of $X_n$, but I can not figure out how to proceed from there. I am new to this part of the theory and would be more than happy about suggestions where to find literature covering similar problems.
Any help is appreciated! Please let me know if the question wasn't precise enough.

What does it mean that $\Pi = { X_n: n \in \mathbb N }$? One is a Poisson random field which is measure-valued on $\mathbb R$ and the other is a countable collection of real-valued random variables.

You probably mean $\beta>1$ and then $(X_n:n\in{\mathbb N})$ represent the points in decreasing order with $X_1$ being the maximum, but you need to clarify.

Yeah, I also think $\beta$>1, otherwise I don't see a reason there shouldn't be an infinity of $X_n$ that are "big". And by the equality I mean more precisely: for almost every $\omega$ in the state space there exists a decreasing sequence of $x_n$ s.t. $\Pi(\omega) = {x^{\omega}_n,n \in \mathbb{N}}$, and I name $X_n(\omega) = x_n^{\omega}$. I am not at all sure why the $X_n$ are measurable [$(\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$] with $\mathcal{S}$ being the smallest sigma algebra that renders the counting operation on all Borel-sets measurable.
